# Using Selenium to test internet explorer in different document modes

Tags: testing, selenium, internet-explorer-9

Is it possible to change the document mode in Internet Explorer using selenium.

I was looking over a feature request during the development of WebDriver but did not see what ended up happening with it.

I was also looking for a command line parameter that I could use to force Explorer into a specific document mode. Though I'm new to using WebDriver and don't know if it supports that.

The question is how can I use Selenium to test Explorer in a specific document mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the following isn't via Selenium, but it is the only way I know of right now.

The DocumentMode can be controlled via a `meta` header tag on the page.  [Defining Document Compatability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  And you can modify a web response before it gets to the browser using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/)  Thus, you can setup Fiddler to add a meta content tag to each response.  I did a quick proof-of-concept by adding the code below to the FiddlerScript `OnBeforeResponse` handler.  After saving the change, loading a page resulted in that page being in the prescribed document mode (below it is IE8).

```
oSession.utilReplaceInResponse("</title>", "</title><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=8\" >");
```

Note:  If you set the Document Mode via the F12 tools, remember that holds for that page until the browser is closed, so if you aren't seeing expected behavior, re-open IE.

Comment: I really wish they had a programmatic way of doing this through Selenium. However, this is a really clever trick.